# How to remove last html entity in PHP

Tags: php, html

I have the folowing code where a arrow is added with html entity in foreach loop. This html entity is in a span tag. I want to remove the last arrow.

```
$btn = '<div style="margin: 5px;">';
if (count($rslt) > 0) {
    foreach ($rsltas as $key => $val) { //added as here
        $btn .= "<a class='btn btn-md'  href='index.php?target=$trgtName#" . trim(substr($val, 0, strpos($val, '-'))) . "'>" . $val . "</a><span style='font-size:50px'>&rarr;</span>";
    }
}
$btn = rtrim($btn, '<span>&rarr;</span>');
print $btn . "</div>";
```

I tried with `rtrim` but this changes the whole html page. There is any other solution to remove the last html element in php `foreach`.

Comment: Just don't add it on the last iteration of the loop.

Comment: Also, you're adding `<span style='font-size:50px'>&rarr;</span>` but trimming `<span>&rarr;</span>`

Comment: i want to trim the whole element between `<span></span>`

Comment: `trim(), ltrim(), rtrim()` doesn't match whole strings. It's just a list of characters to trim away, not a string to trim away.

Comment: Thats not true @MagnusEriksson, you CAN trim strings.

Comment: `$str = 'test test test test'; print rtrim($str, 'test');` Is working just as expected. Prints out test three times.

Comment: @ManuelMannhardt - Yes, if the string contains those characters. But it will still remove it per _characters_, not by the full string. `trim('hello nas', '<span>')` will return `hello ` since all the characters `nas` exists in `<span>`.

Comment: Yes, you are right. Will still remove if the full string was not found.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's definitely tons of duplicates, but I can't find one. So, you have two, no, **three** solutions:

- Use a counter and add `&rarr;` by condition

  ```
  $btn = '<div style="margin: 5px;">';
  if (count($rslt) > 0) {
      $i = 1;
      foreach ($rslt as $key => $val) {
          $btn .= "<a class='btn btn-md'  href='index.php?target=$trgtName#" . trim(substr($val, 0, strpos($val, '-'))) . "'>" . $val . "</a>";
          if ($i < count($rslt)) {
              $btns .= "<span style='font-size:50px'>&rarr;</span>"; 
          } 
          $i++;
      }
  }
  print $btn . "</div>";
  ```
- Add items to array and `implode`'em with `&rarr;`

  ```
  $btn = '<div style="margin: 5px;">';
  $btns = [];
  if (count($rslt) > 0) {
      foreach ($rslt as $key => $val) {
          $btns[] = "<a class='btn btn-md'  href='index.php?target=$trgtName#" . trim(substr($val, 0, strpos($val, '-'))) . "'>" . $val . "</a>";
      }
  }
  $btn .= implode("<span style='font-size:50px'>&rarr;</span>", $btns);
  print $btn . "</div>";
  ```
- `substr` fnal string with length of last `span`. Here you may need to use `mb_`-functions if your data is multi-byte encoded.

  ```
  $btn = substr($btn, 0, -1 * strlen("<span style='font-size:50px'>&rarr;</span>"));
  ```

Comment: Thanks @u_mulder.

Comment: Instead of using a counter, I usually prefer flipping the logic around for stuff like this - checking for whether we are currently processing the first record is easy via a boolean flag. So if it is _not_ the first record, output span with arrow first; output link afterwards.

Answer (score 0):

**Steps:**

1) Take an iterator variable say `$i`.

2) Take count of result set: `$cnt`.

3) Increment counter in loop.

4) Check if `$i` is less than `$cnt`, add `<span>`, else don't add.

5) No, need to remove, add condition before adding.

You can add an iterator variable and check if it is last `str_replace()`

```
$cnt = count($rslt);
$i=0;
$btn = '<div style="margin: 5px;">';
if ($cnt > 0) {
    foreach ($rslt as $key => $val) {
        $btn .= "<a class='btn btn-md'  href='index.php?target=$trgtName#" . trim(substr($val, 0, strpos($val, '-'))) . "'>" . $val . "</a>";
 if ($i < $cnt) {
 $btn .= "<span style='font-size:50px'>&rarr;</span>";
 }
 ++$i;
    }
}
```

Comment: i want to add arrow for all the foreach except the last one.  is there as solutuion with rtrim. or similar function

Comment: Why do you want `rtim()`?

Comment: so that i dont have to do so many steps. I was looking for a one line solution.